# VBA Find String Then Compare Dates

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to compare dates and if Column G = "Yes" then compare the date in "C" & RowNumber to copy in range specified, but it seems nothing happens at all.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim range1 As Range
Dim CellValue As Range, CellValues As Range
Dim RowNumber As Integer, ColumnLetter As String, ColumnNumber As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set range1 = wb.Sheets("Evals (P)").Range("A5:H10")

For Each CellValue In range1
    
    RowNumber = CellValue.Row
            
    If CellValue.Range("G" & RowNumber).Value = "Yes" Then
            
        If CellValue.Range("C" & RowNumber).Value >= DateValue("A4") Then
                        
            ws1.Range("A283", "H283").Value = CellValue.Range("A" & RowNumber, "H" & RowNumber)                                                                            
            
        ElseIf CellValue.Value = "No" Then
            
        End If

    End If
            
Next CellValue
```

Comment: Okay... any problems so far? Questions?

Comment: I'm not seeing any errors.

Comment: I'm not seeing any question... keep in mind that we can't see your spreadsheet, so inferring what needs to happen from that one-liner description isn't as clear as it could be.

Comment: The code is not performing any action. It does not recognize if there is a string with a Yes or No. I click run. And it literally performs no expected action.

Comment: I've fixed your indentation, but `CellValue` is already representing one single cell, so `CellValue.Range("G" & RowNumber)` is rather hard to conceptualize... I think you might want to use a simple `For...Next` loop that goes from 5 to 10, and then use that for your row number, and then you can use `Worksheet.Cells(row, column)` to retrieve any particular cell without needing to work out "column letters". Also consider just outright deleting any dead code, like that `ElseIf` condition and empty block.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` (hit F9 on that line), and then run it; when the breakpoint is hit, run/debug your code line by line by pressing F8 to step into the current statement, and use *immediate* and *locals* toolwindows to inspect locals' runtime values / compare. If execution jumps to a place you're not expecting, you've found the bug!

Comment: Shouldn't DateValue("A4") be something like DateValue(Range("A4").Value), perhaps with a worksheet reference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, CellValue.Range will cause troubles, I'll propose you to test this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
'Dim range1 As Range
'Dim CellValue As Range, CellValues As Range
Dim RowNumber As Integer, ColumnLetter As String, ColumnNumber As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
'Set range1 = wb.Sheets("Evals (P)").Range("A5:H10")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Evals (P)")

For RowNumber = 5 To 10
    
    'RowNumber = CellValue.row
            
    If ws1.Range("G" & RowNumber).Value = "Yes" Then
            
        If ws1.Range("C" & RowNumber).Value >= DateValue(ws1.Range("A4")) Then
                        
            ws1.Range("A283", "H283").Value = ws1.Range("A" & RowNumber, "H" & RowNumber).Value
            
        ElseIf ws1.Range("G" & RowNumber).Value = "No" Then
            
        End If

    End If
            
Next

'
Set ws1 = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
```